# Vue router starting route cant be redirected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

The problem I'm currently having is that my `'/'` route with vue-router shows an empty page.

my route looks like this

```
const route = [
   {
    path: '',
    component: HomeTemplate,
    children: [
     {
      path: '/home', component: Homepage
     }
    ] 
   }
 ]
```

How can i redirect my  `''` or `'/'` route to a page not found component

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const route = [
   {
        path: '/home',
        component: Homepage
   },
   {
        // other routes ...
   },
   {
        path: "*",
        component: PageNotFoundComponent
   }
 ]
```

If you want wrap one component into another, use `<slot></slot>` element, read here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots

Example:

ParentComponent:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Something fun -->
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>
```

Child Component:

```
<template>
  <parent-component>
    <!-- Something else -->
  </parent-component>
</template>

<script>
import ParentComponent from 'path-to-parent-component'

export default {
  components: {ParentComponent}
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have to use the HomeTemplate. I made my menubar/ sidebar in that component

Comment: Follow my example, you can wrap `Homepage` component into `HomeTemplate`.